# How do I make it not show the first line on the cmd window of the bat file executing the code?

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a steam bot. I have made a bat file to open the Node.js file that the code is on.

I don't want the first line in the cmd of what the bat file opened to be shown. Is there any way to do it not using the `start` command, because it makes it open in a Node.js terminal when I do that and I need to be in the cmd. The cmd window:

[image]

When I use the `start` command (that I don't want to use):

[image]

Tried to use the start command but turns out it opens it in a special window of Node.js.

Here is the batch file for now:

```
node bot.js
pause
```

It shows that in the cmd when the batch file runs:

```
C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Steam Bot>node bot.js
```

Comment: Does the usual `@echo off` thing work?

Comment: thanks alot it works great now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suppress output of commands, the secret is to disable `echo`:

```
@echo off

node bot.js
pause
```